# overriding a specific spring boot health indicator

Tags: spring-boot

Is there anyway to override the output of a specific health indicator?

Specifically in the built-in ones, I would like to change the information that it returns by one of my own.

e.g.  the mongo health indicator has a bad side effect that it can take a long time to timeout and we have found this to be disastrous to our monitoring.  Now when we get timeouts on getting the health endpoint it is pretty much because the heath ping to mongo is waiting to timeout, ergo mongo is unreachable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I can see to do this is to disable the default mongo health indicator and create your own. To disable you set the property for `management.health.mongo.enabled` to `false`. Then to create your own just look at the `MongoHealthIndicatorConfiguration` and make a similar class for your health monitor. The important part is to replace the `MongoHealthIndicator` class with your custom indicator class. The existing `MongoHealthIndicator` has this for the health check:

```
@Override
protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
    CommandResult result = this.mongoTemplate.executeCommand("{ buildInfo: 1 }");
    builder.up().withDetail("version", result.getString("version"));
}
```